# Comparing Coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have the equation:

$4m(m-1)x^m .\sum_{i\geq 0}a_ix^i+x^m.\sum_{i\geq 0}a_ix^i=0$ ; $a_0\neq 0$

why am I able to say that

$4m(m-1)+1=0$?

I would understand if the equation rather than being an equality ($=$) it was instead an equivalence ($\equiv$) (Just compare the coefficients for $i=0$)

but if you have the equation $ax^2=0$ you cannot say that $a=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write the  first  equation as

\begin{align*}
4m(m-1)x^m\sum_{i\geq 0}a_ix^{i}=-x^m\sum_{i\geq  0}a_ix^{i}\qquad\qquad     a_0\neq 0
\end{align*}

It  seems  that this  equality is treated   as   equality    of *[Power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series)* which are known to be equal (within their radius of convergence) if and only if the coefficients of corresponding powers are equal.

> The coefficient of $x^m$ on the left hand side is $4m(m-1)a_0$ and the coefficient of $x^m$ on the right hand side is $-a_0$. We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> 4m(m-1)a_0&=-a_0\qquad\qquad a_0\neq 0\\
> 4m(m-1)&=-1
> \end{align*}
>
> and since $a_0$ is not equal to zero, we can divide by $a_0$ and the claim follows.

Within this context your last example $ax^2=0$   is to interpret, that it is an equation valid  *for all $x$*. If we do so, $a=0$ follows.

Comment: Assuming of course that the radius of convergence is not 0. Which I think you covered by saying WITHIN.

Comment: @user254665: Correct. If the radius of convergence is zero, i.e. the series diverge, the comparison as stated above is not valid.